# oAuth 1.0 server in php

Tags: php, oauth

I am developing an application to provide some dynamic content for cloud platforms.

Currently i am testing out with cloud application.

```
The cloud application send request with the following query parameters,
oauth_consumer_key=
oauth_nonce=
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
oauth_timestamp=
oauth_version=1.0
oauth_signature=
```

here, i don't know what to do with these parameter values.  I read some tutorials that i have to validate those using oauth_signature.  And some tutorials told to send access_token and so.

so, please tell me what i have to do within my application with those query parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: You should read up on OAuth and how to implement it (or what library to use) and then come back if you have a specific question. As it is, this seems too broad.

Comment: Any clues or learning method or any other guide?